# Sharepoint Online SPFX Web parts React - How to dynamically choose script based on enviro?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I want to dynamically choose which script to use in my web part.

My imports are as follows:

```
import * as jQuery from 'jquery';
import 'jqueryui';
```

And I want to do this in my component:

```
//Select script to us 
//if (Environment.type === EnvironmentType.Local) {
  //import * as jQuery from 'jquery';
  //import 'jqueryui';
//} else if (){
   SPComponentLoader.loadCs('//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');
  SPComponentLoader.loadScript('//code.jquery.com/jquery-min.1.12.1.js');
} ;
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can make use of `require` method somewhat as below:

```
//Select script to use 
if (Environment.type === EnvironmentType.Local) {
    require('jQuery');
    require('jqueryui');  
} else if (){
   SPComponentLoader.loadCss('//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');
   SPComponentLoader.loadScript('//code.jquery.com/jquery-min.1.12.1.js');
};
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks Gautam.

Comment: Cheers, happy to help. If it helped you, could please mark it as answer. Its just a checkmark besides the answer. To know more, please check [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)